# Google Chart draws nothing using PHP array to send data

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, charts

I'm trying to take a array from PHP code returned from my CodeIgniter model/controllers and display at my page view. But, the chart is not generated, maybe because it's not getting the right data.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$data = array(
    $generateChart['A'],
    $generateChart['B']
);
json_encode($data);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('string', 'city');
      data.addColumn('string', 'date');
      data.addRows(<?php echo $data; ?>);

      var options = {
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<div class="row">

    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;" class="col-md-4">
    </div>
```

If I send this:  I receive the data everything fine!

Created a new question more specific about my problem: [Google Charts won't work if passing JSON data but works with fixed data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37814813/google-charts-wont-work-if-passing-json-data-but-works-with-fixed-data)

Comment: can you share a sample of `$data`?

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 10 - TATUÍ [1] => 1 - CONCÓRDIA [2] => 928 - PONTA GROSSA [3] => 928 - PONTA GROSSA [4] => 928 - PONTA GROSSA ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 13.06.2016 [1] => 13.06.2016 [2] => 13.06.2016 [3] => 13.06.2016 [4] => 13.06.2016 ) )

Answer (score 1):

couple things...

1. see the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for `PieChart`
   first column should be `'string'`
   second a `'number'`
   `'date'` column is invalid
2. the array format from the comment won't work
   you need an array for each row, which should have a value for each column

something like...

```
Array(
  [0] => Array(
           [0] => 10 - TATUÍ
           [1] => 12
         )
  [1] => Array(
           [0] => 1 - CONCÓRDIA
           [1] => 13
         )
  [2] => Array(
           [0] => 928 - PONTA GROSSA
           [1] => 14
         )
)
```

Comment: Something like that? <?php
$teste = array(
    [0] => array(
            [0] => "Teste",
            [1] => 20
        )
);
?>