# Google Charts won't work if passing JSON data but works with fixed data

Tags: php, json

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$chart_arr = ['2016', 5000];
json_encode($chart_arr)
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {

      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Task');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Hours per Day');
        data.addRows(<?=json_encode($chart_arr)?>);

      var options = {
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));

      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>

<div class="row">

    <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;" class="col-md-4">
    </div>
```

With that code, the chart won't display. Otherwise, if I just echo the json_encode in PHP, it echo exactly as the GCharts wants to. Example: ["2016",5000]. As I tried here:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <?=json_encode($chart_arr)?>
</div>
```

It seems very confuse to me. Never thought that work with charts would be so confusing.

Comment: Could you try unifying the array contents, at the moment 2016 is a string and 5000 is an integer. Either remove the quotes of 2016, or add them to 5000. Are there any console errors?

Comment: Are you getting some output in the js console?

Comment: Thanks for the tips about seeing the console. Changed to: data.addRows([
        <?=json_encode($chart_arr)?>
                    ]); and it works!